# Method Chains PHP OOP

Tags: php, oop, methods

Commonly, in a lot of frameworks, you can find examples of creating a query using the query builder. Often you will see:

```
$query->select('field');
$query->from('entity');
```

However, in some frameworks you can also do it like this

```
$object->select('field')
       ->from('table')   
       ->where( new Object_Evaluate('x') )
       ->limit(1) 
       ->order('x', 'ASC');
```

How do you actually do this kinds of chains?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is called [Fluent Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) -- there is an [example in PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#PHP) on that page.

The basic idea is that each method *(that you want to be able to chain)* of the class has to return `$this` -- which makes possible to call other methods of that same class on the returned `$this`.

And, of course, each method has access to the properties of the current instance of the class -- which means each method can "add some information" to the current instance.

Comment: You're welcome :-) ;; yes, each method can set/change properties, and the "last" method is often used to "execute" whatever the previous methods were called to configure.

Comment: Not sure using fluent interface will always make code easier to read ;;; when it's used to build some SQL query, for instance, it makes sense ; but when the methods are not really related, not so sure -- depends on the situation, I suppose ;;; a great thing being that even if your methods return `$this`, they can be called "in a typical way".

Comment: Does it have to return `$this`? Can't it return `$that` and continue from there?

Comment: @PascalMARTIN So there isn't a way to trigger the host method (with all the method set values) without casting a string using Fluent Interfaces?

Answer (score 7):

Basically, you have to make every method in the class return the instance:

```
<?php

class Object_Evaluate{
    private $x;
    public function __construct($x){
        $this->x = $x;
    }
    public function __toString(){
        return 'condition is ' . $this->x;
    }
}
class Foo{
    public function select($what){
        echo "I'm selecting $what\n";
        return $this;
    }
    public function from($where){
        echo "From $where\n";
        return $this;
    }
    public function where($condition){
        echo "Where $condition\n";
        return $this;
    }
    public function limit($condition){
        echo "Limited by $condition\n";
        return $this;
    }
    public function order($order){
        echo "Order by $order\n";
        return $this;
    }
}

$object = new Foo;

$object->select('something')
       ->from('table')
       ->where( new Object_Evaluate('x') )
       ->limit(1)
       ->order('x');

?>
```

This is often used as pure eye candy but I suppose it has its valid usages as well.

Comment: Use case: `$setup = $Object->add_component($component_property)->configure($component_properties);` Where Object::add_component() returns the Component object it added as a property of $Object (eg. to an array), and it is configured with the Component::configure() method. Without chaining, we would have to determine that last element added to the $Object->Components array, then get the Component object that way.

Comment: @AVProgrammer - Your example does not make use of `return $this`, does it?

Comment: Yes it does, the Component object does this, to allow for the configure() method.

Answer (score 2):

```
class c
{
  function select(...)
  {
    ...
    return $this;
  }
  function from(...)
  {
    ...
    return $this;
  }
  ...
}

$object = new c;
```