# OOP - Classes and Subclasses - Call subclass method

Tags: php, class

I was wondering if this syntax is correct:

On Classes.php:

```
Class Cart {

   public $Product; // an object handler will be set on this property

   public function __construct($user) {
   // get a product on user's cart (let's say it's only 1 product) - returns $id
   $this->Product = new Product($id);
   }
}


Class Product {

   public function __construct($id) {
   // construct goes here
   }

   public function Product_Method() {
   // product method goes here
   }

}
```

On Script

```
$cart = new Cart($user);
$product_method = $cart->Product->Product_method();
```

It looks alright to me, since $product is set as Public and refers to an object handler.

Comment: what is Product_method() i do not see in definiton

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: Why don't you try it in your compuer? A useful related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307097/method-chains-php-oop

Comment: @chandresh_cool I would assume it is in the product class that is not shown.

Comment: It's not what I'd call a subclass, more calling a method on a property, but as long as `$cart->Product` isn't `unset()` this would work yes.

Comment: okay got it just wanted to double check :)

Comment: I did not defined the Product_method() because is not relevant for the doubt. The doubt is related if is indeed possible to call a subclass method throught a class property (which is set to an object handler) $class->property->Method();

Comment: Did you even try it? @LucasTourinhoCavalcante

Comment: Yep. Did not worked for me. But I'm hoping that was some code mistake and not an unproper syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various things you could mean by "correct" here.

1. **Syntax**

   Your syntax is correct. You could have easily discovered this by running your code, so I'm not sure if this is what you're asking about.
2. **Correctness**

   As others have said, `$id` isn't present in the scope of the constructor. This will result in a runtime error.
3. **Best Practices**

   [Dependency injection](http://www.developerknowhow.com/php-dependency-injection-explained/) is all the rage these days. Calling `new` from a constructor is discouraged. Instead, you'd pass in your `Product` object. Note that this is somewhat subjective, if that sounds unnecessarily complicated nothing *forces* you do it, but at least be aware of why people are against it so that you can make an informed decision.

   Also, depending on your use case, it may be better to encapsulate the functionality so that outside code doesn't have to know about `Product`'s methods (it just has to deal with a cart). That is, make `$Product` private and add a method to `Cart` that is responsible for calling `Product_method()`. This may or may not make sense depending on the semantics of  `Product_method()` (is it something that a `Cart` should know how to do?).

Comment: Also just a terminology nitpick: `Product` isn't a "subclass". That term  strictly refers to [inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_\(object-oriented_programming\)). What you're doing is [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).

Comment: Dear Matt, Thank you for your detailed response. It solved my doubt entirely and yet gave me another aspects of the problem to think about. Regarding the dependency injection, could I ask you to clarify this passage: "Instead, you'd pass in your Product object". I did't catch the proposed "way-out".

Comment: Looking at your new comments and edits since I wrote this, you were indeed asking about syntax. [If you're getting errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221318/oop-classes-and-subclasses-call-subclass-method/16221756#comment23200762_16221318) it'd be helpful to know what they are; perhaps you should post a new, more specific question.

Comment: @LucasTourinhoCavalcante: It's simple really, just with some complicated-sounding terminology. The calling code would do this:
`$product = new Product(); $cart = new Cart($user, $product);`.
And Cart's constructor would set `$this->Product` to the passed-in object. I'd also recommend a [type hint](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) if you go this route.

Comment: Ooh I got it now. The problem is, when i construct the Cart, I have no clue of which products may be inside it. Yet, I will need to call determined Product's methods for each Product, so I can access the prices, comissions, sizes, and calculate total . I the present scenario, the Cart is really composed by several Product's objects, reason why I believe that Dependency Injection will be not that bad. Thank you again Matt, I really appreciate your help. Best regards,Lucas

Answer (score 0):

you are using $id in the constructor by passing it to `new Product($id)`, but where are you getting $id from? And you just have a string floating in the function with no echo or assigning to a variable.

Comment: I did no put the entire classes because the doubt is related to the validity of this: $class->property->method(). Being property the object handler created on the __construct

Answer (score 0):

what is the $id ? you need to set $id in construct

```
Class Cart {

   public $Product;

   public function __construct($user,$id) {
   "get a product on user's cart (let's say it's only 1 product)"
   $this->Product = new Product($id);
   }
}
```

and in your code

```
$cart = new Cart($user,$id);
$product_method = $cart->Product->Product_method();
```